# Ubuntu 14.04 Apache2 404 Page Not Found

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, http-status-code-404

I've setted up an Ubuntu 14.04 with php5, Apache2, mysql / mysql-php.
Now I am tring to visit mydomain.com/admin but its response the following error
**The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.** 
Here is my mydomain.com.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/mydomain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**mod_rewrite** is already enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the domain because you haven't properly configured a live domain. Go to http://localhost:80/admin to access your information. I would try setting the server name equal to your public IP address and set the server alias equal to localhost. Then you'll be able to access the server from over the web by entering your public IP address into the URL of your HTTP client.